# How to resize images for best view in Word and PDF document?

Tags: image-editing

I have prepared some vectoral and python/matplotlib high resolution images. As you can see from pictures, whenever I'm zooming there's no problem in quality but if I upload the image to a Word document some blurring is happening. If I convert the Word document to PDF, the blurring is increasing. How do I adjust the images for best view and is it possible doing it in Photoshop? Or do I need to draw/plot the images in appropriate pixels?

High Quality:

[image: High Quality 1]

Low Quality (From PDF):

[image: Low Quality 1 (From PDF)]

Answer (score 1):

Select and copy the vector graphics

In Word use the Paste Special option and select Enhanced Metafile (EMF)

The EMF is the 32-bit version of the Windows Metafile (WMF) and it's Microsoft specific vector graphic file format

The vector graphics pasted as EMF will be resizable without any loss of quality and the PDF generated by Word will be as sharp as in Word at any zoom level

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile